# How to run files as a project in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn `Vue.js` as well so I create a simple folder called VueTest.

I have two files in the folder:

- app.js
- index.html

I found the info on how to configure the task runner to open up the current file and I have that setup to open in Chrome, which it does. However, because it's not running as a project, my `index.html` doesn't see the `app.js` file and so my Vue project is not working correctly. I just runs the HTML code an all I see is my mustache code (ex: `{{Title}}`).

How do I run files as a project?

Answer (score 0):

If get it correct - you want to launch js app without opening teminals outside 'VS Code' then you have to see [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, it's actually easy and I should have figured this out before posting.

To run Index.html on it's own, all I had to do was make a script reference in the page pointing to the app.js file. I didn't have to do that in JsFiddle.

Answer (score -1):

you can't run files as a project in VS Code. it is just a text editor.